# Use instance for input checking?

Tags: haskell, instance

I am trying to make a game and I want to ask the player a question. If their answer is yes, something happens or no something else happens.

```
class Status a where
    stat :: a -> String

instance  Status Char where
    stat _ =  "Would you like to drink a potion? YES or NO?"
```

Doing this way will check all Char types but I can't use String. Can I do this in a different way?

Comment: Why should this problem require typeclasses/instances? What about `if answer=="yes" then ... else ...` ?

Comment: I need to write this at least 20 times so was wondering if I could it with instances instead and make my code shorter.

Comment: @user35053 just wrap it in a function you can call 20 times?

Comment: If one of the answers satisfies you, you should click the check mark to accept it. Otherwise, you should comment on them and/or edit your question to explain what's missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want

```
main = do
    putStrLn "type yes or no"
    response <- getLine
    if response == "yes"
        then putStrLn "You typed yes"
        else putStrLn "You didn't type yes"
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want something like this instead:

```
import Data.Char

getStatus :: String -> IO Bool
getStatus question = do
    putStrLn (question ++ " YES or NO?")
    response <- getLine
    return (toLower response == "y")

main = do
   res1 <- getStatus "question1?"
   res2 <- getStatus "question2?"
   .
   .
   .
   res20 <- getStatus "question20?"
   doSomething [res1, ..., res20]
```